# Python circular reference importing doesn't work when using "as"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Let me first establish what working scenario.

```
main.py
module/file1.py
module/file2.py
```

**main.py**

```
import module.file1
print(module.file1)
```

**module/file1.py**

```
import module.file2
```

**module/file2.py**

```
import module.file1
```

Running `python3 main.py` gives me the following, which is fine.

```
<module 'module.file1' from '/project/module/file1.py'>
```

Now, if I change **module/file2.py** to have the following:

```
import module.file1 as testtt
```

I get this new output (error):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import module.file1
  File "/project/module/file1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import module.file2
  File "/project/module/file2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import module.file1 as testtt
AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'file2'
```

I'm guessing that python doesn't fully evaluate the imported module when simply importing, causing the circular reference to blow up only when you immediately use it within either of the two files.

I'd imagine I also would not get the error if I used the module in a function, since that would be evaluate when the function is actually called, like this:

```
import module.file1

def test():
    print(module.file1)
```

What is the recommendation here? Should I just work to remove the circular reference? It seems like code smell anyway (existing code base).

Comment: Downvotes? Can this question be asked differently?

Comment: I'm surprised at the down votes. I puzzled over this for a quite awhile before I realized what was happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an implementation detail. The `import` statement uses the `__import__` function to do the work of finding and importing the module and then binds its returned module to the `as testtt` variable.

When doing a nested import like `import module.file1 as testtt`, `__import__` returns the base module ("module"). Since the importer still needs to bind "file1" to the local namespace, it has to look up the submodule name "file1" on that object. Since the import of file1 is still in progress, it hasn't been bound to the "module" module yet.

It works in the `import module.file1` case because `file1` isn't bound to the local namespace and doesn't need a lookup.

There are many pitfalls with circular imports that will bedevil you throughout your code's life cycle. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

"import" is an executable statement, so you can just do the import inside the function

```
def test():
    import module.file1
    print(module.file1)
```

Comment: Makes sense. It seems my suspicion is correct that with just ```import module``` python will lazy execute the imported module until it is actually used. If you use the module at all (or alias the import), it causes it to get executed.

Comment: nope, it's not a "lazy" import.  (Put some print statements in there to prove it to yourself.)  The import mechanism DOES say "hey, if this module has already been imported, don't re-import it."

Comment: I guess I am not understanding then why it fails ONLY when you use ```import module.file1 as testtt``` or ```print(module.file1)```. Something is being delayed, no?